# Can't figure out how to generate coordinates(x,y) entered by the user

Tags: c++

Can't figure out how to generate coordinates(x,y) entered by the user and find the closest genareted point to the one that the user has entered.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>//for generating a random number
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x,k,y,quad,x1,y1;// the variables that we are going to use
    cout << "Enter the value of x : "<<endl;
    cin >>x;
    cout << "Enter the value of y : "<<endl;
    cin >>y;
    cout <<"Enter the amount of numbers you want to be generated : "<<endl;
    cin >>k;//how many coordinates to be generated
    srand(time(0));//to make sure that the numbers are random
        for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){

        int x = rand() % k;//generate x
        int y = rand() % k;//generate y
        x1 = x;
        y1 = y;

        cout << "(" << x << "," << y <<")"<< "\n\n";
    }
    if (((x1*x1)+(y1*y1))<(x*x)+(y*y)){
        cout <<"("<<x1<<","<<y1<<") is the nearest point to ("<<x<<","<<y<<")"<<endl;
    }

    if (x<0 && y<0){//these are to show in which quadrant are the coordinates
        quad = 3;
    }
    else if(x<0 &&y>0){
        quad = 2;
    }
    else if(x>0 && y>0){
        quad = 1;
    }
    else if(x>0 && y<0){
        quad = 4;
    }
    else if(x<0 && y==0){
        quad = 5;
    }
    else if(y<0 && x==0){
        quad = 6;
    }
    else if(x>0 && y==0){
        quad = 7;
    }
    else if(y>0 && x==0){
        quad = 8;
    }
    switch(quad){
        case 1: cout <<"("<<x<<","<<y<<")"<<"are in the 1st quadrant"<<endl;break;
        case 2: cout <<"("<<x<<","<<y<<")"<<"are in the 2nd quadrant"<<endl;break;
        case 3: cout <<"("<<x<<","<<y<<")"<<"are in the 3rd quadrant"<<endl;break;
        case 4: cout <<"("<<x<<","<<y<<")"<<"are in the 4th quadrant"<<endl;break;
        case 5: cout <<"("<<x<<","<<y<<")"<<"are between the 2nd and 3rd"<<endl;break;
        case 6: cout <<"("<<x<<","<<y<<")"<<"are between the 3rd and 4th"<<endl;break;
        case 7: cout <<"("<<x<<","<<y<<")"<<"are between the 1st and 4th"<<endl;break;
        case 8: cout <<"("<<x<<","<<y<<")"<<"are between the 1st and 2nd"<<endl;break;
        default : cout <<"("<<x<<","<<y<<")"<<"are in the (0,0)"<<endl;break;


    }
}
```

I know that the solution is probably simple, but i just couldn't figure it out. I'm freshman in college and i feel pretty retarded 
for asking questions like this, but this is my last hope.
Any help will be appreciated.^^

Comment: What part are you stuck at? Your code seems to want to find quadrants, but your question seems to be about exact coordinates.

Comment: Hello! I want to find a way to generate not random numbers, but numbers related to the x,y entered by the user and from these numbers to find the point that is the closest to the initial x,y.

Comment: Also, you initially take x and y as input, and without storing them anywhere, you are overwriting them in the for loop. I think that is a mistake as well. What do you mean generate numbers related to x, y instead of random numbers?

Comment: Yes, but even when i set x and y beforehand i still don't get the nearest random number to the initial x and y, but what i get is the last saved random number. A.K.A how can i make it so it loops through the generated numbers and find the closest to the initial x,y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this code 
 I didn't use quadrants as you wanted to find closest point to the given point.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

float dist(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) { 
    return sqrt(pow((x1-x2),2) + pow((y1-y2),2));   
}

int main()
{
    int x,y,k;
    cout << "Enter the value of x : "<<endl;
    cin >>x;
    cout << "Enter the value of y : "<<endl;
    cin >>y;
    cout <<"Enter the amount of numbers you want to be generated : "<<endl;
    cin >>k;//how many coordinates to be generated
    //Define arrays for points, 
    int *X = new int[k];
    int *Y = new int[k];
    srand(time(0));//to make sure that the numbers are random
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){

        X[i] = rand() % k;
        Y[i] = rand() % k;

        cout << "(" << X[i] << "," << Y[i] <<")"<< "\n\n";
   }
   float minDist = dist(x,y,X[0],Y[0]);
   int number = 0;

   for( int i = 1; i < k; i ++ ) {
        if( dist(x,y,X[i],Y[i]) < minDist ) {
        minDist = dist(x,y,X[i],Y[i]);
        number = i;
    }
}

cout << "Nearest point (" << X[number] << "," << Y[number] << ")";
cout << "Distance is " << minDist;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what i needed. Thank you so much!